# Why does my program crash immediately after calling delegate?

Tags: c#, interop

I'm trying to wrap [this function](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_AddEventWatch) defined by SDL2.

It's signature is

```
void SDL_AddEventWatch(SDL_EventFilter filter, void* userdata)
```

Where `SDL_EventFilter` is

```
typedef int (SDLCALL * SDL_EventFilter) (void *userdata, SDL_Event * event);
```

Thus, I've defined my wrapper like so:

```
public delegate int EventFilter(IntPtr userData, IntPtr type);

[DllImport("SDL2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SDL_AddEventWatch")]
public static extern void AddEventWatch(EventFilter filter, IntPtr userData);
```

And I'm testing it like so:

```
SDL.AddEventWatch((data, e) =>
{
    return 0;
}, IntPtr.Zero);
```

When I run my program it actually enters the lambda function, but then immediately crashes as soon as it exits the function ("vshost32.exe has stopped working").

What might be causing the crash?

Comment: What's the exception? Did you check in Debug mode?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: I am running in debug mode. This is C# interop, it's calling a DLL written in C. It's a hard crash, no exception.

Comment: Have you checked the System logs?

Comment: @EZSlaver: What system logs?

Comment: Your delegate declaration is only compatible with an __stdcall function pointer.  It is quite unclear what SDLCALL might mean.  Use the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute on the delegate to make it match.

Comment: @HansPassant: Added `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]`; still crashes exactly like before

Comment: Well, no, that's what it already was.  If you don't know what SDLCALL means then guess at Cdecl.  It is better that you know so you don't have to guess.

Comment: @HansPassant: I misread the source code as `STDCALL` not `SDLCALL`. You were absolutely right, `Cdecl` works, and `SDLCALL` is defined as `#define SDLCALL __cdecl`. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 #define SDLCALL __cdecl
```

You have a calling convention mismatch.  Your native code requires a __cdecl function but your C# code declares a delegate that will be mapped to a an __stdcall callback.  The default for unmanaged code interop.  You must declare it like this:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int EventFilter(IntPtr userData, IntPtr type);
```